# I am a godot user, I have been following a Godot Tutorial, buy Godot says that

Tags: game-engine, game-development, godot, gdscript

> Invalid set index 'weapon' (on base: 'Spatial') with value of type
> 'Spatial (weapon_manager.gd)'.

My code is below:

```
extends Spatial


# All weapons in the game
var all_weapons = {}

# Carrying Weapons 
var weapons = {}

#HUD 
var hud

var current_weapon #Reference to the current weapon extension??? 
var current_weapon_slot = "Empty" # The current weapon slot

var changing_weapon = false
var unequipped_weapon = false 



func _ready(): 

    hud = owner.get_node("HUD")

    all_weapons = {
        "Unarmed" : preload("res://Unarmed.tscn"),
        "Pistol_A" : preload("res://pistol_a/pistol.gd"),
        "Rifle_A" : preload("res://rifle_a/rifle_a.tscn")
    }

    weapons = {
        "Empty" : $Unarmed,
        "Primary" : $Pistol_A,
        "Secondary" : $Rifle_A
    }

    # Initializing refernces for each weapon
    for w in weapons:
        if weapons[w] != null:
            weapons[w].weapon_manager = self
            weapons[w].player = owner
            weapons[w].visible = false
        
        
    # Set current weapon to unarmed
    current_weapon = weapons["Empty"]
    change_weapon("Empty")
    
    # Disable process 
    set_physics_process(false)



func _process(delta):
    
    if unequipped_weapon == false:
        if current_weapon.is_unequip_finished() == false:
            return


    unequipped_weapon = true 

    current_weapon = weapons[current_weapon_slot]
    current_weapon.equip()

    if current_weapon.is_equip_finished() == false:
        return
        
    changing_weapon = false
    set_process(false)



func change_weapon(new_weapon_slot):

    if new_weapon_slot == current_weapon_slot:
        current_weapon_slot.update_ammo()
        return

    if weapons[new_weapon_slot] == null: 
        return

        current_weapon_slot = new_weapon_slot
        changing_weapon = true 

        weapons[current_weapon_slot].update_ammo()

        # CHanging weapons
        if current_weapon != null: 
            unequipped_weapon = false 
            current_weapon.unequip()

    set_process(true)
    
    
    
    # Update HUD
func update_hud(weapon_data):
    var weapon_slot = "1"
    
    match current_weapon_slot:
        "Empty":
            weapon_slot = "1"
        "Primary":
            weapon_slot = "2"
        "Secondary": 
            weapon_slot = "3"
            
    hud.update_weapon_ui(weapon_data, weapon_slot)
```

Comment: to be more specific, this error happens at these lines, for w in weapons:
    if weapons[w] != null:
        weapons[w].weapon_manager = self
        weapons[w].player = owner
        weapons[w].visible = false

Answer (score -1):

Your `weapon_manager.gd` file seems to lack a variable called `weapon`, and thus setting it is impossible.

Also, I can't find where the error would originate in this script file; it probably originated somewhere else in your code.
Make sure you're using the right variable names, and trying to set values on the right objects.